# In Swift, how can I change the image on a button and change it back after the user has seen the original (ie. flipping a card over)?

Tags: swift, uiimage, delay

```
sender.setBackgroundImage(imageArray[index], forState: .Normal)

sleep(2)         // wait before you flip back over

sender.setBackgroundImage(cardBack, forState: .Normal)
```

The sleep seems to stop the image from completing its load.  How can I wait for the `setBackgroundImage` to complete?

Comment: You *never* wait. You use the information *when it's available*. With a "callback" for example - UIAnimation has some interesting ones.

Comment: why don't use closure?

Comment: But the above code is in a callback.  Before the callback was invoked, CardBack was displayed as the BackgroundImage.  Should I display a UIAnimation of front and back images?   And can you use an animation on a button?

Comment: Is the UI responsive while you are sleeping? If not, and your touches lag or are ignored, it is definitely the wrong way of implementing. Take a look at the UIView.animateWithDuration() function. You can flip your card (or in this case, change your image over a specified time) and then reverse the process in the completion block with a closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sender.setBackgroundImage(imageArray[index], forState: .Normal)
sender.enabled = false;

let delay_time = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), 2 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
dispatch_after(delay_time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    sender.setBackgroundImage(cardBack, forState: .Normal)
    sender.enabled = true;
}
```

**Edit:** Disable the button while it is showing the image.

Comment: Thanks.  This works and I learned about closure.  But why is image somewhat transparent (or perhaps its brightness increased)?